# Starting iphone. UITableView Hello world with edit button fails

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

im learning Obj-C and im treating to make my first UITableView with  "Hello world" text.

My problem is i can't show on screen right edit button. this is my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault   reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}
[[cell textLabel] setTextAlignment:(UITextAlignmentCenter)];
cell.textLabel.text=@"Hello World";
//[cell.textLabel setText:@"Hola2"];
return cell;
}
```

and:

```
- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=self.editButtonItem;
}
```

Am I missing something?

Thanks for help.

Comment: NO problem in this code it's working fine.

Comment: If you are learning iPhone development, I strongly suggest you [check this out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7296695/beginning-iphone-development-in-xcode-4/7296894#7296894).

Answer (score 4):

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=self.editButtonItem;
```

This must go in the viewDidLoad

are you also setting the rows and sections correct?

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Oh my god i feel so stupid, i wrote it on wrong method, tyvm!!